# python - numpy image, crop one side, fill with black the ther

Tags: python, image, numpy, crop

I have a image with resolution 816x624, and would need to make a 640x640 image out of it.

To do so, i'd have to crop the long side (centered), and fill up the short side with black (centered). the resulting image should be the center of the starting image, with a small black strip on top and bottom.

How can this be done?

i tried with:

```
 crop_img = img1[int(h1 / 2 - 640 / 2):int(h1 / 2 + 640 / 2),
                           int(w1 / 2 - 640 / 2):int(w1 / 2 + 640/ 2)]
```

but this does not work because h1 i ssmaller than 640.

[image]

Comment: can you add how your sample image looks like?

Comment: @Bhargav I added a quick paint drawing to explain better what I would need. the black in the left picture is my starting image, the yellow is the size of the desired destination image, and on the reight is the resulting image.

Comment: are your pixels in range `[0, 1]` or in range `[0, 255]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an imput image `img`, an expected height `h` and an expected width `w`:

```
def resize_img(img, h, w):

  #cut the image
  cutted_img =  img[
      max(0, int(img.shape[0]/2-h/2)):min(img.shape[0], int(img.shape[0]/2+h/2)),
      max(0, int(img.shape[1]/2-w/2)):min(img.shape[1], int(img.shape[1]/2+w/2)),
  ]

  #pad the image
  padded_img = np.zeros(shape=(h,w,3), dtype=img.dtype)
  padded_img[
      int(padded_img.shape[0]/2-cutted_img.shape[0]/2):int(padded_img.shape[0]/2+cutted_img.shape[0]/2),
      int(padded_img.shape[1]/2-cutted_img.shape[1]/2):int(padded_img.shape[1]/2+cutted_img.shape[1]/2),
  ] = cutted_img

  return padded_img
```

some exaples:

```
url = "https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2020/02/france-in-pictures-beautiful-places-to-photograph-eiffel-tower.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
start_img = np.array(PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
plt.imshow(start_img)
plt.show() #shape = (487, 730, 3)
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(resize_img(start_img, 640, 640))
plt.show() #shape = (640, 640, 3)
```

[image]

I tested on some other pictures:

`shape = (1020, 680, 3)`

[image]
[image]

`shape = (450, 254, 3)`

[image]
[image]

`shape = (847, 564, 3)`

[image]
[image]

All resized images have size `(640, 640, 3)` and seem to be properly padded.

PS. I have used the following libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import PIL
import requests
from io import BytesIO
```

Comment: Grazie Salvatore! :) works like a charm. Question not related to the topic: how did you create the imaes with the pixel scala?

Comment: prego :) Actually there is no reason to do it. I have used `pyplot.imshow` to plot the images, and it by default generates the ticks, but I think there are many ways to remove them.

Comment: No need to remove the ticks, they're perfect.  They demonstrate very well that the code is working properly.

Comment: yeah, agree with Mark, no need to remove them. I just asked to learn something new coz they are cool.

Comment: @sharkyenergy ok great! Happy to read that!